# Windows shell that works with windows and linux commands

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

I'm a linux user forced to work on windows. I want a windows command line that understand windows and linux commands. Furthermore

- It has to save history
- It has to be able to ssh directly to a server
- Easy theming
- Free

Git bash understands linux commands but it doesn't understand windows commands. So I can't just copy paste a folder path into it, I have to switch `x\y` to `x/y`

[This terminal](https://github.com/Eugeny/terminus) is awesome, pretty much everything I ask for, except it does not understand linux commands.

So I want a terminal that understand both windows and linux, like `ls` and `dir`. I don't like powershell, you cannot ssh with ease, its theme is bad and you can't theme it with ease. I just don't like it.

Comment: I don't think there are shells that understand both at the same time. What should be done for example when you set alias that is a command in the other shell? For `linux` environment on `windows` I recommend `cygwin` and `unxutils`.

Comment: Being in a similar situation (Linux user forced to work on Windows), I usually revert to [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/). Has a portable version (which makes a "let's try" easy) and comes with an embedded Cygwin. Doesn't meet your requirements fully, as on its (Cygwin) command line you cannot simply drop Windows specific commands with paths, but it will run Windows executables fine.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I think I might have found a better solution, please read my answer

Comment: @Izzy think I might have found a better solution, please read my answer

Comment: Why not [enable Linux Subsystem for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)?

Comment: @ThisIsNotMyRealName I did not know i could do that, but now that I know, i don't know if i'd use it, because that means i'd be stuck in powershell or cmd, no multi tabs and a bad theming mainly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed [cmder](http://cmder.net/), I don't know much about it yet but it seems to

- understand linux and windows paths and commands
- have git and ssh and vim preinstalled
- save history
- have tabs
- good themes
- command completion

And much more, I think this has everything I need.

Comment: Good find (+1), looks very interesting! Do you know if it will run on Win7 as well? Coudn't find a note on their site (might have missed it, though).

Comment: @Izzy it seems to run https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1552  but some users say it was slow and they blamed minGW, this was in 2017, not sure if it's fixed. In any case it runs and you might want to try and see if it's still slow

Comment: Takes a little "getting used to", but I already like it (for specific tasks) :)